# Improve data transfer for SqlFileStream?

Tags: sql-server, tcp, filestream, wireshark

Running `SQL Server 2014` with `FilestreamEffectiveLevel` set to 3. Thus, I can easily retrieve files using [SQLFileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream(v=vs.110).aspx) in `C#`:

```
using (var stream = new SqlFileStream(path, transactionContext,
    FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0))
{
    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

This works, but it looks like this piece of code causes the network to be overwhelmed by `TCP` packages marked with the `PSH` flag. What this essentially means is that the TCP buffers are not used efficiently. Instead of utilizing our `MTU` of 1500 bytes, it mostly uses 54 bytes (empty `ACK`) or 200-300 bytes. (We ran some tests using `WireShark`.)

What is causing this? Is it a driver problem or do we need to change the `C#` code to somehow optimize the network utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be another part of the code. `SqlFileStream` performs well.